# PhP Laravel Remote error not handled by try catch

Tags: php, try-catch, remote-access

So I have this code and I'm trying to catch an error when I can't connect for some reason (wrong credentials or no network connection or something similar), but it is not working and my app crashes with error.

```
try {
    $connection = new Remote([
        'host' => $equipment->ip_address,
        'port' => 22,
        'username' => EquipmentAccess::where('equipment_id', $equipment->id)->first()->ssh_user,
        'password' => EquipmentAccess::where('equipment_id', $equipment->id)->first()->ssh_password,
    ]);
    $command = $request->command . ' ' . $request->argv;
    $ip = $connection->exec($command);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Houston, we have a problem:" . $e;
}
```

If anyone can give me any information about what I missed, it will be highly appreciated.

EDIT: I guess, I wasn't clear enough. It crashes with typical laravel pipeline error and the latest is, that it can't connect to that device. And it should just give me my error message.

EDIT2: here is a link to a SS of the stack-trace - https://gyazo.com/9095d5600be2b7f07ca59d93624f9187

Comment: error msg .. ???

Comment: What error? Remember that errors (not exceptions) are unrecoverable

Comment: Could you post the error stack-trace